# Eclipse: Moving Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, shared-libraries

I'm working on implementing code from one project(we'll call this project "A") into another project (Project "B"). The code from Project A that I need to implement into Project B has Maven Dependencies, and won't work without them.

I was wondering if/how it is possible to simply add the Maven Dependencies Folder from Project A into Project B allowing the code from Project A in Project B to work?

I'm quite new to Maven and this whole thing, so if you could dumb stuff down for me as much as possible I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use maven in project B then you can copy the genrated libraries by maven in project A to project B, do the following:

- In Project A, open the project in Eclips, right click Project A -> Maven - > Update Project, then in project A, open Java Resources - > Libraries - > Maven Dependecies then select all libraries in this folder (hold shift then click the first library and the last library). right click then copy.
- In Project B, make a new lib folder and past into it all of these libraries. Then right click project B -> Properties - > Select Java Build Path - > Select Libraries Tab - > Add Jars - > Select Project B - > Lib Folder - > Select all libraries in Lib folder (hold shift - click first -last) then Ok -> Ok again for the Properties, and you are done.

Comment: Would I need to go about any special ways to make sure the lib is connected and working?

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependencies are generated out of the pom.xml configuration of the project. You need to create (if not already done) a pom.xml and copy the section "dependencies" into the new projects pom.xml.

Comment: So I'd need to create a pom.xml file in Project B, and then simply copy the dependencies section from Project A into it? I'm slightly confused because of the Maven Dependencies folder in Project A; Just setting up the pom.xml file will do the trick?

Comment: The Maven Dependencies folder is derived from what is in the dependencies section of the pom.xml. If you add or remove something from your pom.xml dependencies, it will be reflected in the Maven Dependencies folder.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @MHU's answer, you can do the following.

1. Publish project A to your local maven repo:

   ```
   cd {PROJECT_A_DIR}
   mvn clean install
   ```
2. Add a dependency in Project B's pom.xml to Project A:

   ```
   <dependencies>
     ...
     <dependency>
       <groupId>project-a-group</groupId>
       <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
       <version>1</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in eclipse, you can do this by adding the ProjectA as dependent project in ProjectB traditionally.

However, Maven do much better in dependency control.

First of all, you have to understand how the maven work when you "install" the maven project.

When you do the Maven Install action in ProjectA, it will compile and build the project as a jar file in your local repository.

After this, you can include this jar file by putting dependency element in the pom file of ProjectA

One more remind, whenever you have change on the codes in ProjectA, you have to do Maven install to "update" the jar file in repository or you should "upgrade" the version number and install again.

Otherwise, the change would not take effect on ProjectB